# AJAX in Qt Quick

Tags: ajax, qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm thinking about using Qt Quick to build desktop applications, since it looks more friendly for someone like me that is coming from web development using node.js, but is it possible to do AJAX and populate controls like a `GridView` only using QML?

Comment: AJAX is just the standards for performing a `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-xml-xmlhttprequest-xmlhttprequest-example-qml.html

Or, for Qt5:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html